# Waiting for player to push button JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Hi so I'm making a Simongame and I need to wait for the player to push a series of button (sending integers to a list) and compare it to another list, but I didn't find any wait for event type of function. So how can I make my game loop wait for the player to push a certain number of button before trying to compare it?

```
start.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Game = 1;
            While(Game == 1)
                //Game adding random values to a list  
                //4 Buttons Action event adding values to another list with 4 different values and a button to validate the values put into the list

                //HERE I need the loop to wait for buttons to be pushed and validated by another button before trying to compare the two list

               //Comparing the two lists , printing a message if they are not the same or returning in the loop and add a new value to the randomly generated list                 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: GUI APIs like JavaFX are using event-driven features. The user at any time may (or may not) click the some button, fill some text field, close the application and so on. So, your program can wait until the end of time without any help of yours. What you need is actually to fire event when condition is true (e.g. all 4 buttons are clicked), and handle that event.

Comment: Your code is trying to fight against the event-driven structure of the library -- don't do this.  As this is not a linear console program and shouldn't be written as if it were. Instead think of setting the object state (fields of the object) and varying its behavior to events (button click) based on that state.

Comment: I suggest you start with a more simple program. Maybe a very simple calculator.

Comment: Thanks everyone so it seems I was just wrong on how javafx really worked , so i will try something more simple from now to begin and i will get back on it later .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. I'm serious, JavaFX is built around event handling.
What you're trying to do is poll for data, but you don't need to. You can add a Click event handler using

```
myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        //TODO all your events and stuff here
    }
});
```

Inside of the handler for the ActionEvent, you can use code to do something. There is another way of handling events for buttons as well, if you want to differentiate between right-clicks and left-clicks, dragging the mouse over or out, etc. This is through the `myButton.addEventHandler(EventType.EVENT), myEventHandler);`.